# Delete All Realm Objects During Runtime

Tags: java, realm

on iOS we can easily call `realm.deleteAllObjects();` to remove all objects in our Realm database.

How do we achieve the same in Android?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this by using results- For instance, if I want to delete all Dog objects, I can do the following-

```
// obtain the results of a query

RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

// All changes to data must happen in a transaction
realm.beginTransaction();

// Delete all matches
results.deleteAll();

realm.commitTransaction();
```

Ref: [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

Comment: This answer is deprecated. See the answer by The Todor for a working solution.

Comment: You should use results.deleteAllFromRealm() instead .. since results.clear() is deprecated. plz update your answer

Comment: in realm 3.5.0 realm.clear() was deprecated you can used delete

Answer (score 23):

**Delete all objects from Realm database:**

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.deleteAll();
    }
});
```

**Delete all objects of a kind from Realm database:**

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.delete(Dog.class);
    }
});
```

**Delete the results of a query:**

```
final RealmResults<Dog> results = realm.where(Dog.class).findAll();

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        // remove single match
        results.deleteFirstFromRealm();
        results.deleteLastFromRealm();

        // remove a single object
        Dog dog = results.get(5);
        dog.deleteFromRealm();

        // Delete all matches
        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});
```

Comment: Great examples. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 8):

For now `clear()` is deprecated. Instead, referring to [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) you should use `results.deleteAllFromRealm()` or `realm.deleteAll()` or `realm.delete(Dog.class)`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm use this for delete all objects:

```
    private void clearAllRealmPerson(){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.clear(Person.class);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           try {
       val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realm.beginTransaction()
        realm.delete<Dog>()
        realm.insertOrUpdate(dogs)
        realm.commitTransaction()
        realm.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.message
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE 3.7.0**

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.deleteAll();
//else realm.delete(obj_A.class);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more your answer? I cannot find what changed in 3.7.0 regarding this topic. Thank you.

Comment: in previous version of Realm, there was `clear(A.class);` method which is deprecated in newer version. @DavidMiguel

Comment: `clear` was [deprecated in version 0.89.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecated-7) not in 3.7.0.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the Realm API has changed. According to [the docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#deleting-objects), this is now the way

```
let all = realm.objects(Books.self)
realm.delete(all)
```

Don't forget to wrap it in a transaction if you haven't already.

```
    try! realm.write {
            let all = realm.objects(Rogets.self)
            realm.delete(all)
        }
```